# Converting Unix Timestamp to a more user-friendly datetime format

Tags: php, unix, datetime, timestamp

I have a javascript datetimepicker that I downloaded online which I use to select a start time and end time of a booking.

However, when I select a date and time it is displayed in this format in the input box - 03/12/2012 04:00 pm, as a string I believe.

What I've done so far is use the strtotime function which is successfully converting the times into unix timestamps so they can be compared.

However, for storing the start and end times in my mysql database and displaying them to the user I need the date and time to be displayed in a more user friendly and readable datetime format such as 03/12/2012 04:00 or 03/12/2012 04:00:00.

Does anybody know if this is possible and if so how to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this workflow.

1. Convert `03/12/2012 04:00` to timestamp by `strtotime()`
2. Convert timestamp to MySQL format by `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);` or using DateTime

   ```
   $dt = new DateTime();
   $dt->setTimeStamp($timestamp);
   $mysql_date = $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
   ```
3. When you retrieve the date from mysql parse it again with `strtotime()`
4. Echo it back to HTML/JS as `DateTime::format("d/m/Y h:i:s a")`;

   ```
   $dt = new DateTime($mysql_date);
   $user_friendly_date = $dt->format("d/m/Y h:i:s a");
   ```

Links of interest

- [DateTime::__construct()](http://php.net/datetime.construct)
- [DateTime::format()](http://php.net/datetime.format)
- [DateTime::setTimeStamp()](http://php.net/datetime.settimestamp)
- [date()](http://php.net/date)
- [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime)

Comment: If you believe its helpful, why not up-vote so that it can stay on top

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL database also supports storing datetime formats, e.g. 2012-03-11 23:44:15. If you store them as datetime they can also be easily compared against other dates. How about that?